# WC Купоны в корзине

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как выводить список доступных купонов пользователю в корзину при покупке товара на который действует купон?

Answer (score 1):

Ниже приведён рабочий код плагина для вывода доступных пользователю купонов в корзине.

На сайте `test.kagg.eu` есть 3 купона:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`coupon 2` ограничен для использования только с почтой `test@gmail.com`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зайдите на страницу shop, добавьте любой товар в корзину и вы увидите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`coupon 2` не выводится в списке, в силу ограничений.

Код плагина:

```
<?php
/**
 * Coupons in the cart
 *
 * Plugin Name: Coupons in Cart
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.org/plugins/coupons-in-cart/
 * Description: Shows available coupons in the cart.
 * Author: KAGG Design
 * Author URI: https://profiles.wordpress.org/kagg.eu/
 * Requires at least: 5.0
 * Tested up to: 5.4
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Stable tag: 1.0.0
 *
 * Text Domain: coupons-in-cart
 * Domain Path: /languages/
 *
 * @package coupons-in-cart
 * @author  KAGG Design
 */

/**
 * Check if user can use a coupon.
 *
 * @param array $posted Post data.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function cic_get_customer_coupons( $posted ) {
    $args = [
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'orderby'        => 'title',
        'order'          => 'asc',
        'post_type'      => 'shop_coupon',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
    ];

    $coupons = get_posts( $args );

    $coupons = array_filter(
        $coupons,
        function ( $coupon ) {
            $wc_coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon->ID );

            if ( ! $wc_coupon->is_valid() ) {
                return false;
            }

            // Get user and posted emails to compare.
            $current_user  = wp_get_current_user();
            $billing_email = isset( $posted['billing_email'] ) ? $posted['billing_email'] : '';
            $check_emails  = array_unique(
                array_filter(
                    array_map(
                        'strtolower',
                        array_map(
                            'sanitize_email',
                            [
                                $billing_email,
                                $current_user->user_email,
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                )
            );

            // Limit to defined email addresses.
            $restrictions = $wc_coupon->get_email_restrictions();

            if ( is_array( $restrictions ) && 0 < count( $restrictions ) && ! WC()->cart->is_coupon_emails_allowed( $check_emails, $restrictions ) ) {
                return false;
            }

            $coupon_usage_limit = $wc_coupon->get_usage_limit_per_user();
            if ( 0 < $coupon_usage_limit && 0 === get_current_user_id() ) {
                // For guest, usage per user has not been enforced yet. Enforce it now.
                $coupon_data_store = $wc_coupon->get_data_store();
                $billing_email     = strtolower( sanitize_email( $billing_email ) );
                if ( $coupon_data_store && $coupon_data_store->get_usage_by_email( $wc_coupon, $billing_email ) >= $coupon_usage_limit ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    );

    return $coupons;
}

/**
 * Before cart action.
 */
function cic_woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals_action() {
    ?>
    <div>
        <strong><?php esc_html_e( 'Available coupons:', 'coupons-in-cart' ); ?></strong>

        <?php

        $coupons = cic_get_customer_coupons( WC()->checkout()->get_posted_data() );

        foreach ( $coupons as $coupon ) {
            ?>
            <div><?php echo esc_html( $coupon->post_title ); ?></div>
            <?php
        }

        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals', 'cic_woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals_action' );
```